# Use Fast-text to find synonyms from syn-sets

Tags: word2vec, synonym, fasttext

I have synsets of Sinhala Language which I extracted from a dictionary, I want to create a fast-text model using those synsets and want that model to provide the synonyms.
can I get that using fast-text or is there another way to accomplish this task?

synsets are like this
[අත දරුවා,කුඩා සතා,බබා,බිලිඳා,බිළිඳා,සප්පයා,සිඟිත්තා,ළදරු,ළදරු ගති ඇත්තා,ළදරුවා]
this is the synset for the word "ළදරුවා" which is "Baby" in the English Language

Comment: If you already have a dataset of synonyms, why do you additionally need a FastText model? Why not just use the authoritative synonym-sets you have? (Creating a FastText model would require a large corpus of realistic language usage, and even when such a model was created, its idea of "word similarity" won't be identical to our sense of "synonymity" – in word-vector models, even **antonyms&& tend to be quite "close" to each other in vector-space, as they are similar to each other in most aspects of usage, only reversed in some narrow specific sense.)

Comment: @gojomo so you think it is better to create wordnet like thing using those synsets? without trying thing like fast-text? thing is how I train a model to read the words without making vectors?

Comment: If you already have synsets of Sinhala, don't you already have a "wordnet like thing"? What is the extra thing you're trying to create? Why do you think FastText will help? (Its "similarity" measures are correlated with, but can't reliably distinguish between, relationships like synonymy, antonymy, hypernymy, huponymy, etc that would be reflected in a true WordNet-quality lexicon.) Why do you want to "train a model to read the words"?

Comment: @gojomo I wanted to create something look like a thesaurus so it will give similar words and the similar words of the context. Can I achieve it in a different way?

Comment: When you say you "have synsets", aren't those synsets already usable as a thesaurus? Also, word-vector models like FastText aren't sufficient to build a true thesaurus, because as mentioned above, "most similar" words in these models will include many words other than synonyms.

Comment: @gojomo so is there any other way for me to do this using machine learning technique because I need to predict the words which are not in the synsets like fasttext

Comment: It's still not clear to me what your goal is. Where are the words that are not in the synsets coming from? What kind of prediction needs to be made? Why?